# PostgreSQL error when extracting table data via JDBC from Spark

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, pyspark, hawq

I had the Spark to HAWQ JDBC connection working, but now two days later there's an issue with extracting data from a table. Nothing's changed on the Spark configuration...

Simple step #1 - printing the schema from a simple table in HAWQ
I can create a SQLContext DataFrame and connect to the HAWQ db:

```
df = sqlContext.read.format('jdbc').options(url=db_url, dbtable=db_table).load()
df.printSchema()
```

Which prints:

```
root
 |-- product_no: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- price: decimal (nullable = true)
```

But when actually trying to extract data:

```
df.select("product_no").show()
```

These errors pop up...

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): 
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not write 3124 bytes to temporary file: No space left on device (buffile.c:408)  (seg33 adnpivhdwapda04.gphd.local:40003 pid=544124) (cdbdisp.c:1571)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2182)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1911)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:173)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:615)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:465)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:350)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JDBCRDD$$anon$1.<init>(JDBCRDD.scala:372)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JDBCRDD.compute(JDBCRDD.scala:350)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1772)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:208)
```

Things I've tried (but willing to try again if there's more precise steps):

- Tried a 'df -i' on the HAWQ master node and there's only 1% utilization
- Tried a dbvacuum on the HAWQ database (VACUUM ALL isn't recommended
  on HAWQ)
- Tried creating this tiny new db (with the single table, 3
  columns), no luck

This can't be an actual memory deficiency so where and what is tripping this up??

Comment: Could be a permission problem. Please check the postgres log; you are swimming in muddy water. With sunglasses. /ORM

Comment: Please show the full, unmodified output of `df -h` and `mount`, as well as `SHOW temp_tablespaces` from `psql`. Also +1 and thanks for showing full stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> could not write 3124 bytes to temporary file: No space left on device

The volume used for tempfiles is filling up. Then the temp file will be deleted on error, so you don't actually see the full volume in `df`.

This could be a tempfs, like `/tmp`, on most Linux systems. If so, it's backed by virtual memory. To confirm, check `mount` and check the setting of PostgreSQL's `temp_tablespaces` (`SHOW temp_tablespaces`). If it's blank PostgreSQL will use the default tablespace, which is unlikely to be a tempfs, but if it's set check where that tablespace is. If it's a on tempfs you may need to move it.

It could also be somehow filling the main tablespace, but that's exceedingly unlikely if it's only at 1% utilization at the moment. Perhaps a massively runaway recursive CTE could do it, but it's unlikely.

Quota management is also a possibility. Perhaps a filesystem quota is configured?

Comment: You're right @Craig Ringer, thank you! I wasn't seeing the /tmp being filled up. Sure enough, it was at 100% utilization. Don't know what gets written there, but HAWQ can't update tables so it just creates new ones (...and more new ones, who knows if there are any references?). One final note: the general admin account didn't show that 100% utilization, only after running `df` as root did the problem reveal itself.